# Scala, call the "self" object in arguments

Tags: scala, arguments

I'm actually running this code in Scala

```
val obj2 = obj1.method1()
val result = obj2.method2(obj2.name)
```

I would know if is somehow possible use the obj2 in a argument concatenating the calls, to clarify I would write something like

```
val result = obj1.method1().method2(_.name)
```

where _ is referring to the object previously computed.
I don't know if it's possible, it's just a style question, the first code works fine

Comment: @manub, I have placed the underscore because in Scala it's often use for this kind of thinks, and I would simply clarify what I would do, but actually is not the correct syntax and doesn't work, so I would know if could be possible obtain something like that

Answer (score 3):

We can do this (borrowing `into` name from http://combinators.info/):

```
implicit class Into[A](x: A) {
  def into(f: A => B) = f(x)
}

obj1.method1().into { x => x.method2(x.name) }
```

Comment: thanks, I think that it is the solution more close to what I want, I hoped for a "prettier" way, but I don't thinks is possible

Comment: If that's what you want, you can do it simpler: `Some(obj1).map(_.method1).map { x => x.method2(x.name) }.get`

Comment: ‛into‛ as defined here is generally named ‛|>‛ aka the "forward pipe operator"